# Any idea for list out aws ec2 instances that expose to internet?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have more more than 200 instances how can I check verify which aws instance are exposed to the internet?

Comment: Programmatically or with an AWS service? https://aws.amazon.com/security-hub/

Comment: @user3783243 if in programming? is that way to scripting to check ?

Comment: Very likely, I dont know it though. Probably look up security groups, see which are open to the world, then see which of those are assigned to instances.

Comment: How do you define "Exposed"? Is there a particular port you care about (eg HTTP on 80, SSH on 22), or is it "any" exposure on any port? Are they all in public subnets?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Yes like, SSH and HTTPs. that is too many instances, I'm thinking to use aws cli to do it. is it possible to capture those "expose" instance?

Answer (score 2):

For an Amazon EC2 instance to be "exposed" on the Internet (meaning that it permits some form of **inbound connection**, the following is required:

- The instance needs to be in a **Public Subnet** (defined as having a Route Table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- The instance needs a **public IP address**
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance needs to permit **Inbound** connections from the Internet

Therefore, to determine whether a particular EC2 instance is "exposed to the Internet", you would need to loop through every instance in every Region and check all of the above. The Security Group is the hardest because there can be multiple security groups associated with an instance, and multiple Inbound rules in each security group.